# PyQT5- Storing users' inputs from an opening window prompt into excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

I am trying to save users' inputs from an opening window prompt into an excel file.
I tried something in the lines of code between 53-59, but it does not work. Can you please help how can I solve this issue?

Also, in every new user entry, new information should be placed on the bottom lines of excel table. It should not overwrite the previous inputs.

Many thanks

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialogButtonBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from xlwt import Workbook

class InputDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Information Window")
        self.first = QLineEdit()
        self.second = QLineEdit()
        self.third = QLineEdit()
        self.fourth = QLineEdit()
        self.fifth = QLineEdit()
        self.sixth = QLineEdit()
        self.seventh = QLineEdit()

        dlglayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        formlayout = QFormLayout()
        formlayout.addRow("Fırst Name:", self.first)
        formlayout.addRow("Second Name:", self.second)
        formlayout.addRow("Age:", self.third )
        formlayout.addRow("Sex:", self.fourth)
        formlayout.addRow("Marital Status:", self.fifth)
        formlayout.addRow("Education:", self.sixth)
        formlayout.addRow("Job:", self.seventh)
        dlglayout.addLayout(formlayout)
        btns = QDialogButtonBox()
        btns.setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QDialogButtonBox.Save)
        dlglayout.addWidget(btns)

        btns.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        btns.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def getInputs(self):
        return self.first.text(), self.second.text(), self.third.text(), 
        self.fourth.text(), self.fifth.text(), self.sixth.text(), self.seventh.text()

wb = Workbook()

sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

sheet1.write(1, 0, 'First Name')
sheet1.write(2, 0, 'Second Name')
sheet1.write(3, 0, 'Age')
sheet1.write(4, 0, 'Sex')
sheet1.write(5, 0, 'Marital Status')
sheet1.write(6, 0, 'Education')
sheet1.write(7, 0, 'Job:')
sheet1.write(0, 1, 'self.first')
sheet1.write(0, 2, 'self.second')
sheet1.write(0, 3, 'self.third')
sheet1.write(0, 4, 'self.fourth')
sheet1.write(0, 5, 'self.fifth')
sheet1.write(0, 6, 'self.sixth')
sheet1.write(0, 7, 'self.seventh')

wb.save('output example.xls')

if __name__ == '__main__':


    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = InputDialog()
    if dialog.exec():
        print(dialog.getInputs())
    exit(0)
```

Comment: The xlwt library is for older binary excel files (Office 2003) and only writes files. Is this what you want?

Comment: If you run the code, you will see that a window pops up and after entering the information requested from you, it saves the informations to the excel table.  But it's not working properly right now, I want to fix it.                                                                                             
By the way, if is there any packages newer than xlwt , I can replace it with a newer one.

Comment: Please be more clear. "It's not working properly" does not mean anything to us. I can only *suppose* that the problem is that the saved file has "self.first", "self.second", etc. Don't ask us to "run to see" (for instance, I cannot use xlwt), explain it to us.

Comment: :) Ok, I'll try my best. The problem is; the saved excel file doesn't show the inputs you entered. It shows the ("self.first", "self.second".... "self.seventh") instead of inputs. But normally, it should show the "First name you entered ", " Second name you entered",..."Job you entered". I hope you understand now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For newer excel files (xlsx), use the `openpyxl` module. It allows reading and writing.

Here is the updated code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialogButtonBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import openpyxl

filename = "data.xlsx"

def checkfile():  # create file if needed
    # check if excel file exists
    import os.path
    from os import path
    if not path.exists(filename):
        # create workbook
        wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

        #sheet1 = wb.create_sheet('Sheet1')
        ws = wb.worksheets[0]

        ws.cell(2, 1).value = 'First Name'
        ws.cell(3, 1).value = 'Second Name'
        ws.cell(4, 1).value = 'Age'
        ws.cell(5, 1).value = 'Sex'
        ws.cell(6, 1).value = 'Marital Status'
        ws.cell(7, 1).value = 'Education'
        ws.cell(8, 1).value = 'Job'
        ws.cell(1, 2).value = 'self.first'
        ws.cell(1, 3).value = 'self.second'
        ws.cell(1, 4).value = 'self.third'
        ws.cell(1, 5).value = 'self.fourth'
        ws.cell(1, 6).value = 'self.fifth'
        ws.cell(1, 7).value = 'self.sixth'
        ws.cell(1, 8).value = 'self.seventh'

        wb.save(filename)

class InputDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Information Window")
        self.first = QLineEdit()
        self.second = QLineEdit()
        self.third = QLineEdit()
        self.fourth = QLineEdit()
        self.fifth = QLineEdit()
        self.sixth = QLineEdit()
        self.seventh = QLineEdit()

        dlglayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        formlayout = QFormLayout()
        formlayout.addRow("First Name:", self.first)
        formlayout.addRow("Second Name:", self.second)
        formlayout.addRow("Age:", self.third )
        formlayout.addRow("Sex:", self.fourth)
        formlayout.addRow("Marital Status:", self.fifth)
        formlayout.addRow("Education:", self.sixth)
        formlayout.addRow("Job:", self.seventh)
        dlglayout.addLayout(formlayout)
        btns = QDialogButtonBox()
        btns.setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QDialogButtonBox.Save)
        dlglayout.addWidget(btns)

        btns.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        btns.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def getInputs(self):
        return self.first.text(), self.second.text(), self.third.text(), \
        self.fourth.text(), self.fifth.text(), self.sixth.text(), self.seventh.text()

def writefile(data):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    # find empty column
    for c in range(2,100):
       if not ws.cell(2,c).value: break
    # enter data
    for r in range(len(data)):
       ws.cell(r+2,c).value = data[r]
    wb.save(filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    checkfile()  # create if needed
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = InputDialog()
    if dialog.exec():
        writefile(dialog.getInputs())
    exit(0)
```

Comment: At last, this is what I want..Thank you so much, Mike!.